# Invalid Cursor when Passing RefCursor to a function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to execute a function that receives a REFCURSOR and performs some data manipulation.

To test my function I have this SQL/PLUS code:

```
var some_cursor REFCURSOR;

exec :some_cursor := SCHEMA.test_getcursor;

print some_cursor;

variable res varchar2;

exec :res := SCHEMA.second_function(:some_cursor, 'Other_parameter');

print res;
```

Now, the first `test_getcursor` function is a simple function that OPENS the cursor, performs a select query and returns the cursor. It works just fine and it prints `some_cursor` just fine too.

The problem happens when I call the `second_function` and pass the refcursor to it.

Function has the following code:

```
type cursor_row
IS RECORD
(field_1 some_field1%type,
 field_2 some_field2%type,
 field_3 some_field3%type);

 new_row cursor_row;

BEGIN
LOOP
fetch PASSED_IN_REFCURSOR INTO new_row --this is where the function fails
...data manipulation...
EXIT WHEN PASSED_IN_REFCURSOR%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
CLOSE PASSED_IN_REFCURSOR;
END;
```

The error I am getting is `Invalid Cursor`.

I am sure that the type I created has the same number of rows and the same data types as the ref cursor.

What am I doing wrong in this case? I am using Oracle 10g, PL/SQL 10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is your problem:

```
print some_cursor;
```

remove it. by printing the cursor, you've fetched all the records and closed it. so the second function can not read it anymore.

eg;

```
SQL> create procedure two(p_rc sys_refcursor)
  2  is
  3    v_col varchar2(1);
  4  begin
  5    loop
  6      fetch p_rc into v_col;
  7      exit when p_rc%notfound;
  8      dbms_output.put_line(v_col);
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serverout on
SQL> var rc refcursor;
SQL> exec :rc := one;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec two(:rc);
X

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

vs

```
SQL> var rc refcursor;
SQL> exec :rc := one;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

D
-
X

SQL> exec two(:rc);
BEGIN two(:rc); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01001: invalid cursor
ORA-06512: at "TEST.TWO", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

which bombs out on the fetch as the cursor wasn't open. You should check `%isopen` first and raise a defined error if you wanted to give a more useful error back.

Comment: is there any difference between using a function and a stored procedure? It looks like when I use a function and do the same, it comes back saying `Error report: Cursor is closed`